# what is different between devicePixelRatio and dppx?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have do some research about `devicePixelRatio` and `dppx`:

`deicePixelRatio`: returns the ratio of the (vertical) size of one physical pixel on the current display device to the size of one CSS pixel.

`dppx`: dots per ‘px’ unit.

I think they are just the same thing, but I am not sure, am I right?

Comment: `devicePixelRatio` is a non-standard chrome metric while `dppx` is regulated by [w3c](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#resolution-value)

Comment: @Kaiido Make sense, thx.

Comment: `devicePixelRatio` is now a standard feature [w3c](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-window-devicepixelratio)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the world of web development, the device pixel ratio (also called CSS Pixel Ratio and also referred to as dppx) is what determines how a device's screen resolution is interpreted by the CSS.

CSS interprets a device's resolution by the formula: device_resolution/css_pixel_ratio. For example:

**Samsung Galaxy S III**

Actual resolution: 720 x 1280
CSS Pixel Ratio: 2
Interpreted resolution: (720/2) x (1280/2) = 360 x 640

When viewing a web page, the CSS will think the device has a 360x640 resolution screen and Media Queries will respond as if the screen is 360x640. But the rendered elements on the screen will be twice as sharp as an actual 360x640 screen.

Some other examples:

**Samsung Galaxy S4**

Actual Resolution: 1080 x 1920
CSS Pixel Ratio: 3
Interpreted Resolution: (1080/3) x (1920/3) = 360 x 640

**iPhone 5s**

Actual Resolution: 640 x 1136
CSS Pixel Ratio: 2
Interpreted Resolution: (640/2) x (1136/2) = 320 x 568

The reason that CSS pixel ratio was created is because as phones screens get higher resolutions, if every device still had a CSS pixel ratio of 1 then webpages would render too small to see. A typical full screen desktop monitor is a 24" monitor at 1920x1080. Imagine if that monitor was shrunk down to < 5" but had the same resolution. Viewing things on the screen would be impossible because they would be so small.

Here is a tool that also tells you your current device's pixel density:

http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/

Here is a searchable list of device pixel ratios (they accept pull requests via GitHub if you have devices to add to this list)

http://dpi.lv/

Comment: and what about the differences between `dppx` an `devicePixelRatio` ? I mean, that the question, and not "what is device pixel ratio ?".

Comment: "also called CSS Pixel Ratio and also referred to as dppx" - i my opinion mean this is the same.

Comment: @Smudoo Thanks for your answer. It is in great detail.

Comment: @Smudoo yes but they're not. That's the point. also `"device pixel ratio"` !== `devicePixelRatio`;

Comment: that bjango link doesn't work but you can use [ScreenResolutionTest](https://screenresolutiontest.com)  to check Device Pixel Ratio of device

Answer (score 2):

`devicePixelRatio` and `dppx` are exactly the same. The former is called from Javascript, and, the latter is used in CSS.

The browser asks for this value from the OS. The OS defines this value in its display mode. Typical values are: @1x, @2x, @3x, @1.5x.

Via this value, for example, @2x, the OS hints to applications (browser, etc.) that in the current display mode, one logical pixel is equal to two physical pixels (technically, it maybe or maybe not), so, the browser (engine) will use the media in doubled dimension to achieve the highest quality. This is done by the browser engine, not by us.

[DPI versus PPI versus DPPX](https://transang.me/dpi-versus-ppi-versus-dppx/)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the same thing. Qmaster explained device-to-pixel ratio concept perfectly, so there is no need to add anything else about that.

The dot density of a screen (or printer) is the number of dots (pixels) it can show (virtually equivalent to "has" in our current fixed-number-of-dots-screen world) per unit of length. CSS features two units in which to express this magnitude:

- dpi (dots per inch)
- dppx (dots per pixel)

When CSS was created, CRT monitors ruled the world and their dot density was typically something around 96dpi. In fact, the definition of pixel according to CSS3 is:

> The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm’s length. For a nominal arm’s length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm’s length, 1px thus corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).[Link](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#reference-pixel).

One [dppx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolution#dppx) is the pixel density found in a 96dpi screen. Mathematically expressed:

```
1dppx = 96dpi
```

For example, if the pixel density of your 15-inch laptop is 146.9dpi, it's completely equivalent to say its pixel density is 1.53dppx (1.53=146.9/96).

Comment: In the world of CSS media queries they are the same. 
for example Samsung Galaxy S5 has 432 dpi density which would give it 432/96 = 4.5dppx by your formula 
but if you test media queries in chrome dev tools on Galaxy S5: mediaQuery = "(min-resolution: 3.1dppx)";
window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches - you will get false. 
but you will get true for mediaQuery = "(min-resolution: 3.0dppx)"; which means browser is treating devicePixelRatio and dppx as the same thing since devicePixelRatio for Galaxy S5 = 3

Comment: this answer is not correct. Both `dppx` and `devicePixelDensity` have nothing to do with the screen dpi/ppi. They get the value from the OS, and always be the same. [DPI versus PPI versus DPPX](https://transang.me/dpi-versus-ppi-versus-dppx/)